# TensorFlow Lite on a non-android/non-iOS ARM64 platform?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

Have anyone built TensorFlow Lite on a non-android/non-iOS ARM64 platform? tensorflow.org only talks about lite/mobile versions on Android or iOS but it seems the Lite version is meant for broader embedded domain where it can be brought on any 64-bit processor. I'm looking specifically for the support on ARM 64 with plain vanilla linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was able to build it on an MediaTek MT8176-based device running Debian ARM64.

Comment: Can you share the procedure?